# Easy problem with composition of functions driving me crazy

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I was working on a problem in Mathematica (chaos theory and nonlinear dynamics) and I was, quite simply, taking the composition $f(f(x))$ of a function, the logistic map. I've done this a million times before and never had a problem -- I even opened a new kernel and tried, but for *some reason,* my composition just didn't work. The first three lines are my attempt, and the last two are what the composition should be. Please help me, I'm going stir-crazy trying to figure this out. Is it something to do with the newest version of Mathematica?

```
f[x_] := a*x*(1 - x)

f[x_] := a*x*(1 - x)

f[f[x]]
(* x *)

a*(a*x*(1 - x))*(1 - (a*x*(1 - x)))
(* a^2 (1 - x) x (1 - a (1 - x) x) *)
```

Comment: Pay attention to the colour of variables. Anything black has a value set. Did you give `a` a value by any chance, e.g. `a=1/(1-x)`? Simply clear `a` or just restart the kernel.

Comment: aH it worked, thank you, still not sure where I had previously defined $a$ or what I had done, but thanks :')